# Find files through extension using glob

Tags: php, windows, glob

I want to find all files having extension either "tif" or "tiff" in lower or upper case.
Currently I am using the following code:

```
$total_files = glob(BATCH_TIFF_PATH."*.[tT][iI][fF]")
```

But I am getting only those files having `.tif` in lower or upper case

where `BATCH_TIFF_PATH` is a constant path including a `\` in the last of path.

and I also want to restrict not to find either `ti` or `tifff` in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$total_files = glob(BATCH_TIFF_PATH."*.{[tT][iI][fF][fF],[tT][iI][fF]}", GLOB_BRACE)
```

Comment: Try it with `GLOB_BRACE`, forgot to add it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the glob. Unless... What operating system are you testing this on? I suspect Windows, based solely on you saying the `BATCH_TIFF_PATH` has a backslash at the end?

Comment: **[This sounds like it is similar to your problem](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#56231)**, however I do not have a Windows environment to test with. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking exclusively for these two extensions, why not just hardcode them in the regex?

```
\.(tif|tiff|TIFF|TIF)$
```

This will match a dot following by either tif, tiff, TIF or TIFF at the end of the string (filename).

Comment: Tried this but not working $total_files = glob(BATCH_TIFF_PATH."*.(tif|tiff|TIFF|TIF)$")

Comment: be sure to escape the dot character, otherwise it will (should?) act as a special regex operator.

Comment: $total_files = glob(BATCH_TIFF_PATH."*\.(tif|tiff|TIFF|TIF)$"); Not working i think this problem is related to glob method specification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the real batch regex, but this will work generally you just have to adapt it.

`.*\.(tiff?|TIFF?)$`